# Why do the avout accept the title "First Among Equals"?

Tags: anathem

Isn't this kind of self-contradictory political language exactly the type of language the avout would describe as "*bulshytt*"†?  Shouldn't the avout be eschewing this term and using something more straightforward?  (There are many instances in the book where the avout characters call out each other for saying "bulshytt".)

"First" among "Equals" is something any *theoric avout* (physicists and mathematicians, basically) would certainly see as self-contradictory (the "equals" relation in mathematics doesn't allow for designating one element of the relation as "first").  There are many different titles that could be used - "leader", "First Speaker" (as they call it in Asimov's Second Foundation), "tie-breaker", etc., that are not self-contradictory or euphamistic.

†*Bulshytt* is a technical term in the language of the academic/scientific people in the Stephenson novel *Anathem*, defined as follows in the book:

> **Bulshytt** ... (2) ... a more technical and clinical term denoting speech (typically but not necessarily commercial or political) that employs euphemism, convenient vagueness, numbing reputation, and other such rhetorical subterfuges to create the impression that something has been said. ... -- THE DICTIONARY, *4th edition*, ...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112480/discussion-on-question-by-davidbak-why-do-the-avout-accept-the-title-first-amon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 aspects to this answer; the point of view of the narrator, and the structure of the Mathic world.

We must bear in mind that Fraa Erasmas is an Edharian, as are almost all of the people closest to him.  Even Arsibalt, Tulia and Ala would likely have bound to the Edharian Order except for politics in the math that limited the number that could bind to the Order of Saunt Edhar.

The Edharians are exceedingly empirical, questioning even the validity of information from their senses and what is commonsensical.  For example, consider  Fraa Orolo's planing of Erasmas in the kitchen; he belabours Erasmas to find a good argument against the existence of pink nerve-gas-farting dragons; or the discussion they have at Orithena where Erasmas has to try to explain how he knows what Orolo's back looks like even though he can't see it.  Edharians will take things *extremely* literally.

But not all fraas and suurs of the mathic world are Edharians (or other orders descended from the Halikaarnians or the Evenedricians), in fact it appears that the majority of the concent, (and apparently most others) are various offshoots of the Procians (in the Concent of Saunt Edhar, the New Circle and the Old Reformed Faanites).  The Procian-aligned orders are much more willing to use rhetorical language, or language as a tool to achieve an outcome as opposed a tool to investigate an idea.  From Erasmus' description of his encounter with Fraa Corlandin:

> "Orolo is an impressive theorician," Fraa Corlandin said. "I regret that I haven't been suvined by him more."
>
> The flaw in this was obvious: odds were that Corlandin was going to spend sixty or seventy more years in the same math with Orolo. If he really meant what he said, why didn't he simply pick up his stew-bowl and walk across the Refectory to Orolo's table?
>
> Fortunately my mouth was full of bread, and so I did not subject Fraa Corlandin to a withering blast of Thelenean analysis. Chewing my food gave me time to realize that he was just speaking polite nothings. Edharians never talked this way. Spending all my time around Edharians, I'd forgotten how to do it.
>
> I tried to unlimber those parts of my mind that were used for polite conversation: probably a good thing to do anyway, on Apert eve. "I'm sure you could arrange to be suvined by Orolo, if you sat down near him and said something wrong."
>
> Fraa Corlandin chuckled at my joke. "I'm afraid I don't know enough about the stars even to say something wrong."
>
> "Well, today for once he said something that wasn't about stars."
>
> "That's what I heard. Who could have guessed that our cosmographer was an enthusiast for dead languages?"

Where Erasmas much later unpacks that last comment to realize it contains multiple levels of aspersions being cast on Orolo.

What this tells us is that while we are clearly shown what an *Edharian* might consider bulshytt, that doesn't mean that view would even be a majority opinion in the mathic world.

Secondly, the way that "First Among Equals" (*FAE*) is used is not completely inconsistent with its meaning.  The Concent has a heirarchy; there are the Primate and the Wardens Fendant and Regulant, and under them other heirarchs.  The title "First Among Equals" is not applied to any of these who have the authority of their role; FAE is used to refer to the ad-hoc leader of a group that lacks an officially designated leader. (Meaning a leadership role defined in the Discipline of the Mathic world, not a "hey, you're in charge" assignment.)

So we see a FAE of the Valer action team, a FAE of each chapter in a particular math, a FAE of the non-chapter of the Lineage at Orithena, the FAE of the group that retrieves Erasmas to the Convox after Orithena is rodded...  In this context "First Among Equals" isn't a *title* as much as it's an operational designation of who is leading at that moment, where the only thing of importance about them is that they happen to be in charge.

Comment: Hmm.  Good points.  Wonder why it is that I identify, so to speak, so strongly with the Edharians when it is clear the Procians have the upper hand overall (who signed the peace treaty with the PAQT? It wasn't the best mathematical physicist ...)

Comment: Has there _ever_ been a case where the philosophers/scientists run things while the politicians sit back and get lead? :)  Not that all Procians are politicians, like the Lorites who are basically historians, but IIRC all the Rhetors (good enough with language to rewrite history) are Procians, and it seems a given that the Primate will never be an Edharian.

Comment: @davidbak: Because Stephenson wanted you to identify with the Edharians. That's why he picked one of them to be narrator/protagonist, why he casts the Procians in a rather negative light throughout, and why Erasmas's description of the Procians is, to put it bluntly, a pretty bad straw man argument (when compared to real-world mathematical fictionalism). Also, the Procians have the additional disadvantage of being wrong (in-universe) about everything that separates them from the Halikaarnians, so they don't even get the redeeming "initially annoying but right all along" quality.

Answer (score 2):

The Ringing Vale Avout are unique in the Mathic world because of their focus on *emergence*:

> [Confronted with violence] Some of their number were killed.  Some of
> the martial artists performed well, others froze up and did no better
> than those who'd had no training at all.  That sort of situation
> became known as an emergence.  A few of the survivors went on to found
> the Ringing Vale math.  According to Lio, they spent almost as much
> time thinking about the concept of emergence as they did in physical
> training...

It is not difficult to imagine a narrative in which Ringing Vale Avout are judged based on their ability to navigate an emergence - just as Lio tested his ability to respond to violence by having Erasmas punch him, the Vale Avout must have various tests designed to measure their abilities during an emergence.  Avout who can handle an emergence are in some way equals; while each is not equivalent, they share the binary distinction of having passed an important test.

Those Avout who do not pass, would not be chosen as representatives to the Convox at Tredegarh.  So in one sense those Ringing Vale Avout that we meet are equals.

The First Among Equals is the one given command authority, but as we see, the Valers are trained to act independently and without awaiting commands:

> A redshirted woman on the perimeter called out "Fusil" which was a
> ridiculously archaic Orth word meaning a long-barreled firearm.  The
> redshirts to either side instantly turned their backs on her to look
> in other directions.

After her neighbors perform what is clearly a practiced response, the woman takes independent action without reference to command:

> The woman who had called out "Fusil" skipped forward, raising her
> hands, and did a cartwheel that took her to the lid of a trash
> container.  From there she sprang sideways, rolled, and came up near a
> drinking fountain on which she planted a foot to shove off and make a
> violent reversal of direction....  In this manner she made rapid
> progress toward the gunman atop the drummon.

So we see two things which suggest Valers may treat each others as equals with the First Among Equals being a semantic term:

1. Valers divide Avout into those who can handle an emergence, and those who can't.  In this sense all the Valers we see (those allowed to the Convox of Tredegarh) are equals.
2. Valers act as equals during battle, making independent choices as dictated by circumstance and without requiring intervention by the FAE.

Therefore the Ringing Vale Avout have sufficient reason to call their leaders FAE without being guilty of bulshytt.

Comment: OK, as far as this goes, but other orders use FAE as well - Fraa Lodighar is FAE of the Procians at Muncoster (I think it is Muncoster), there are several mentioned by name at Edhar as well.

Comment: If the Procians do it then it probably _is_ bulshytt :)

Comment: To give a slightly less brusque response: You can have someone arbitrarily designated to perform "leader-like" tasks without endowing that person with any actual power. This is what the Valers do, and this is (probably) what the other maths do as well. "First" in this context would be something like an abbreviation of "first to speak" - and perhaps also last to speak. But getting the first or last word does not make one person superior to anyone else, it's just a secretarial function to keep meetings organized.

Comment: @Kevin, @ gowenfawr - Fraa Erasmus had to talk to the FAE of the Edharian order to get accepted there - it could have been a power thing (the FAE had the power to accept or deny), a leader thing (the FAE could give advice, encourage or discourage), or a secretarial thing - I can see it any of those ways ... what do you think?

Comment: @Kevin I think you've got the core of a good answer there, spin it out.  I still think the Valers are unique but that hamstrings this answer's scope.

Comment: @gowenfawr: I'd like to, but it's been several years since I actually read the doorstopper, and my knowledge is pretty hazy.

Comment: @Kevin - "doorstopper" - hmmm, _Dictionary, 4th ed_ says that's _not_ bulshytt when applied to _Anathem_ ... (Though it is one of my favorite fiction works.)  (Now I think of it it might be the only kind of thing Stephenson writes lately ...)